# React-Native Router Flux Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid. Can't solve it using "export default"

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string( for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.

When i try to run the app with my physical device and it shows the error. Does anyone has  the same  problem? I have the method adding the "export default App" but seems likes it doesn't helps.

this is the App.js file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  AppRegistry
} from 'react-native';
import {Scene, Router} from 'react-native-router-flux';

import ListRecipe from './ListRecipe';
import RecipeDetails from './RecipeDetails';
import UpdateRecipe from './UpdateRecipe';
import CreateRecipe from './CreateRecipe';

const App = () => (
  <Router>
      <Scene key="root">
        <Scene key="listR" component={ListRecipe} title="List Recipe" initial/>
        <Scene key="recipeD" component={RecipeDetails} title="Recipe Details"/>
        <Scene key="updateR" component={UpdateRecipe} title="Update Recipe"/>
        <Scene key="createR" component={CreateRecipe} title="Create Recipe"/>
      </Scene>
    </Router>
);

export default App;
```

This is one of the subFile  ListRecipe.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import {Actions}from 'react-native-router-flux'

class ListRecipe extends React.Component{
    render(){
      return(
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text onPress={()=>Actions.recipeD()}>
              Navigate to Recipe Details
            </Text>
          </View>
      );
    }
  }

  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
      backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    },
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you have forgotten to export the ListRecipe from the ListRecipe.js,
unless you do the export you can't get that import statement working in App.js 
and one more thing instead of Scene with key="root" use Stack with key="root" in my point of view

Comment: Thank you for your reply, can you show me how to do the export? and i have tried using Stack with key="root" but  it still have that error.

Comment: I've just fixed it by adding export default for the ListRecipe.js too. Thanks!

Comment: yeah there you go!!